# Asp.Net MVC 3.0 pass Values in upload function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file,string type)
        {
         //  body

```
    }
```

This is an Index function where if I give only file parameter it works but if I wish to give parameter with file to get the value of the dropdown selected item then how should I do in mvc3.0.
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    
    
}
This is what I am using for File Upload.

Select
    Type1

I want the selected value from here help me out to sort out this.

Answer (score 1):

Any values in the same form as the input file will be submitted along with the file and are located in your `Request.Form` collection.